# How to track a download with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I have a download file that is protected with a reCAPTCHA. Is there a way to track the downloads (both attempts and completed) with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search turns up [the answer](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55529). In fact, you can track it several ways. You can use a event handler on the link to the download or put the download on a page that has tracking code on it and have that page serve up the file after the captcha is completed.

However, it cannot track if a download is completed. You need special software for that.

Comment: What's that "special software"? O:-)

Comment: @cfischer Read this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download