# Tracking with Google Analytics both a page and a file linked from it

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I have a page located on a subdomain (downloads.easyjob.net) that links to an executable. The download of the executable is correctly tracked by google analytics (following [these indications](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/how-to-track-a-download-with-google-analytics/18667#18667)).

However, I'd like to track the page itself too. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the tracking code for GA in the page then it will collect stats for the page itself when someone views it. You can also add the virtual link code to track the click on the download link. ([source](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55488))