# Unable to track a subdomain with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I have a download page on a subdomain (downloads.easyjob.net) and I'm tracking the "virtual page view" to the download following [these instructions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/how-to-track-a-download-with-google-analytics/18667#18667) .

That part works fine. However, I also want to track the index page at downloads.easyjob.net and that's where I got into trouble: it gives me the same number of pageviews ass the entire site on www.easyjob.net, which is clearly not possible. Anybody knows what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set things up differently for different [scenarios](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html).

I think you want the Subdomains scenario for your existing syntax, if it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not setup event tracking on the link to start the download instead of a virtual page view, track it as an event? Then you can run reports and see where those events came from organics, paid search, keywords, visitors etc.